# Spark unable to download kafka library

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using Python 3.5 and Spark 2.2 Streaming with Kafka and the script was unable to run due to missing kafka libraries.

I am puzzled why the library was missing/not found even though the dependency information was from Spark's website itself.

```
groupId = org.apache.spark
artifactId = spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11
version = 2.2.0
```

I ran "spark-submit script.py" and the error shows that kafka library is required.

```
Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.2.0 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.2.0.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar> ...
```

On the next run, I ran "spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10:2.2.0 script.py" with the kafka library to be downloaded.

This time round the error shows that it is not able to find/download the library.

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: C:\Users\james\.ivy2\cache
The jars for the packages stored in: C:\Users\james\.ivy2\jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/D:/programs/spark-2.2.0/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
        confs: [default]
:: resolution report :: resolve 2908ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
        :: modules in use:
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.2.0

        ==== local-m2-cache: tried

          file:/C:/Users/james/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.2.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.2.0.pom

          -- artifact org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.2.0!spark-streaming-kafka-0-10.jar:

          file:/C:/Users/james/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.2.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.2.0.jar

        ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

          C:\Users\james\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10\2.2.0\ivys\ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.2.0!spark-streaming-kafka-0-10.jar:

          C:\Users\james\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10\2.2.0\jars\spark-streaming-kafka-0-10.jar

        ==== central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.2.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.2.0.pom

          -- artifact org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.2.0!spark-streaming-kafka-0-10.jar:

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.2.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.2.0.jar

        ==== spark-packages: tried

          http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.2.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.2.0.pom

          -- artifact org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.2.0!spark-streaming-kafka-0-10.jar:

          http://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10/2.2.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-2.2.0.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.2.0: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-streaming-kafka-0-10;2.2.0: not found]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1177)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:298)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: As [discussed on Developers Mailing list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Am-I-crazy-or-does-the-binary-distro-not-have-Kafka-integration-td24608.html), Kafka is not included in binary distribution. That is why you don't have it on classpath.

Second: in your `--packages` command, you should specify Scala version. It's not necessary only in SBT, but `spark-submit` uses Ivy in the background.

So, please try:

```
  $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 script.py
```

Extra point: Maybe I will create a PR to change description, it's misleading

Comment: I even added the scala version, still can't find the library.       My command:  /path/to/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12:2.4.0 script.py.      I get the following:

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                     |            modules                           ||   artifacts            |
 |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------
 |      default     |   6       |   0       |   0        |   0       ||   6        |   0        |
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 3):

Try to write

```
bin/spark-submit --jars yourjarfile.jar --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.4.3 pythoncode.py
```

I had the same problem and I solved it typing like this. I hope that helps.